# How to share the django app in the Network?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-hosts

I want to access my django app by both `localhost` as well as the ip_address of device. How can I do it?

In Flask, we can share the app in network by passing `host='0.0.0.0'` as argument in `app.run()`.

Example: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`
And the flask gives links for both localhost `(127.0.0.1:5000)` and for the network (`ip_address:5000`).

How can I achieve same for Django?

I've tried passing `0.0.0.0` and the 'ip_address' in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list in `settings.py` but didn't work.

I know about command: `python manage.py runserver ip_address:8000`
but then app is not accessible by `localhost:8000` :(

Comment: `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`